# how do i display en dash sign(-) in c?

Tags: c

I can't display - sign in printf statement.

Here is the code I tried:

```
printf("The temperature values must be between −459.67 and 1000\n");
```

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: "The temprature values must be between ΓêÆ459.67 and 1000"

Comment: It works for me, what OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: it's print - sign. what you want?

Comment: i am compiling it on windows cmd

Comment: your dash is a hyphen and not a minus

Comment: and am beginner for c language:(

Comment: I'd expect "temperature", rather than "temprature".

Comment: @chux it's just spelling men

Comment: That temperature is below absolute zero level.  Do you mean negative energy?

Comment: @LuisColorado am no expert on that but i think that is exactly absolute zero temperature in Fahrenheit.

Comment: Sorry, I'm educated with IS in mind. My apologies for my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C uses the minus character (ASCII 45) for the negative sign. Use the same character in the `printf` statement as you do for unary minus.

You are currently using the *en dash* which will not be outputted correctly in a console which only supports UTC-7 encoding.

By the way, is this a quiz?

Comment: Grab a copy of Kernignhan & Ritchie, work through the first chapter *and* complete all the example exercises at the end of that chapter. That will prepare you well for a C test. Good luck with the interview.

Comment: Also use a programmers editor, not Microsoft Word or word processor to type your programs.  Did you copy paste the statement from a pdf file ?